# Marshaling an array of boolean vs marshaling a single boolean (defined as int) to bool in C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

In a C API I have BOOL defined as follows

```
#ifndef BOOL
#define BOOL int
```

And I have a struct which, among others, has a simple BOOL member and an array of BOOLs

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    BOOL    bIsSomething;
    BOOL    bHasSomething[5];
}
```

Now I found out that when I want to cast the whole struct I have to marshal them differently:

the single `BOOL` I marshal with `I1` and the fixed length array I have to marshal with `I4` (if I don't their struct sizes won't match and I will have problems extracting an array of these structs into C#):

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SomenNativeStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] 
        public bool bIsSomething;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 5)]
        public bool[] bHasSomething;
    }
```

I suspect I do something wrong because I'm not sure why I should need to marshal the same type differently depending on whether I get it as a fixed size array or as a single member.
If I'm marshalling them all as `I4` I get a `System.ArgumentException`

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in SomeDll.dll    
Additional information: Type 'Namespace.Document+SomeNativeStruct' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
```

Comment: I think your problem is in bool size in c#. Did you try to change c# struct to match C API (use int instead of bool)?

Comment: Your c++ is using an integer for a bool.  So they are I4 (not I).  So it would be simpler to just make your c# structure int instead of boolean.  Then eliminate the type above bIsSimething which isn't needed.  The remove ArraySubType from bHasSomething.

Comment: Why would you marshal one BOOL as `I1`, and another as `I4`? It sounds like you're just bashing the interop with a hammer until it sort of looks like it works. What's the size of the unmanaged struct? In any case, use `int[]` instead of `bool[]`. Bools aren't blittable, so you really don't want to use them in a byval interop array.

Comment: @Luaan that's what I'm mentioning in the last paragraph. I also don't see why I should marshal one as `I1` and the other as `I4` but this what made it work. I want to understand why I cannot use `I4` for the single bool like for the array. But I guess I can use `int[]` in the native struct and then convert it to a `bool[]` within C#? (and yes, it totally is bashing the interop with a hammer - I'm not saying I want to use it like this :))

Comment: Oh, I get it now - you say that the exception occurs when you *don't* marshal the first BOOL as I1, right? Is the DLL you're invoking a 64-bit DLL? Have you tried attaching a native debugger to inspect the actual memory layout of the structure? Also note that `int` isn't necessarily a 32-bit integer - depending on compiler and platform, it can just as easily be a 16-bit integer, for example. The alignment will also depend on the compiler, so make sure to verify it (either against the specs, or at least the actual layout seen in a debugger). What's true and false for your BOOL? 0 and not-0?

Comment: @Philipp well you definitely should _not_ marshal C member of type `int` (probably 32 bits) as an `I1` (8 bits) with sequential struct layout unless you know you are doing. Try suggested fixes and see if that works.

Comment: @Luaan I changed the marshaling from bool types to `Int32` and removed the `MarshalAs` and now it works. It seems a combination of little endianness and memory alignment made the other structs work but in this case it showed that it was pure coincidence that it had been working in other structs.

Comment: Good for you ;) I've written that as an answer, since it really shouldn't just be a couple of comments at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool` is a tricky type to interop. There's many mutually incompatible definitions of what a boolean value is, so `bool` is considered a non-blittable type - that is, it needs to be truly marshalled, rather than just sticking a "totally a bool" tag to the data. And arrays of non-blittable types are doubly-tricky.

The simplest solution would be to avoid using `bool` entirely. Just replace the `bool[]` with `int[]`, and provided the original type is actually a 32-bit int (depends on the compiler and platform), you'll get correct interop. You can then manually copy the interop struct to a managed struct with a more sane layout, if you so choose - which also gives you full control over interpreting which int values correspond to true and false, respectively.

In general, native interop is always tricky; you need to have a good understanding of the actual memory layout as well as the meaning of the values and types you're dealing with. The types aren't enough - they're too ambiguous, especially in standard C (which is often *the* standard for native interop even today). Headers aren't enough - you also need the docs, and perhaps even a look in a (native) debugger.

Extra danger comes from the fact that there's no safety net that tells you you're doing things *somewhat* wrong - the wrong interop approach can appear to work just fine for years, and then suddenly blow up in your face when e.g. a `true` value happens to be `42` instead of the more usual `-1`, and your bitwise arithmetics breaks subtly (this *can* actually happen in C#, if you use unsafe code). Everything might work great for values smaller than 32768, and then break horribly. There's plenty of hard to catch error cases, so you need extra caution.